# Can exiled players only increase an unused die once if they spend a Food 2 card?

Tags: dead-of-winter

Page 14 of the rules under Exile says

> The exiled player cannot spend food tokens to increase his action die results, but may play food cards to increase an action die result by 1 for each food card played rather than carrying out the effect listed on the food card

The literal reading seems to imply I can only increase a die by 1 for even a Food 2 card.  Is this true or can they increase a die twice or two dice once each with this sort of card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule you quoted clearly says it raises the dice result by one for each food card, so the dice result is raised by one for each food card.

Answer (score 2):

When the Dead of Winter rule book says to spend a food **card**, it doesn't matter what the number on the card is. In this case, if you spent a Food 2 card, it would only count as **one card** and you could only increase a singular die result by one.